# Use PHP to attatch HTML code to DOM element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website backend that lets you upload images to my site, like an alternative to FTP, I want to use this as a backend to my image portfolio, what I want, is once these images upload, it adds this image to my HTML, by adding new DOM elements being new to PHP though, I currently do not know how to do this.

here is my php (modified from W3Schools)

[upload.php]

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo " " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 9000000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large. (10mb limit)";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

and the HTML I want to append to:

[index.html]

```
<body>

<div class="parent">

  <!-- image preview, onlick go to lightbox -->
<a href="#img1" class="">
    <img src="image1.png" class="">
  </a>
  
  <!-- image lightbox -->
  <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img1">
    <span style="background-image: url('1.png')"></span>
  </a>

</div>

</body>
```

I want the PHP to add to my container, with the same exact structure as both the `#img1` DOM elements, so that it creates a new lightbox, also meanting that it should have a new `#img` tag, that will add from the last, for example, say the newest is `#img6`, when uploading to my PHP, the PHP will add a `#img7` element etc etc. and the new elements should be in my parent div.

It should also replace the `src` and `background-image` from 1.png to whatever the image I have just uploading is.

The result I want from from uploading an image with this new code should look like this

```
<body>

<div class="parent">

  <!-- image preview, onlick go to lightbox -->
<a href="#img1" class="">
    <img src="image1.png" class="">
  </a>

  <!-- image lightbox -->
  <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img1">
    <span style="background-image: url('1.png')"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- image preview, onlick go to lightbox -->
<a href="#img2" class="">
    <img src="uploadedthruphp.png" class="">
  </a>

  <!-- image lightbox -->
  <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img2">
    <span style="background-image: url('uploadedthruphp.png')"></span>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ul instead of div and append li elements with every uploaded image in your HTML code. Insert javascript snippets in the PHP part where the image upload is successful. You can echo the PHP variable $target_file there:

index.html

```
<body>

<ul id="parent">

<!-- image preview, onlick go to lightbox -->
<li>
<a href="#img1" class="">
<img src="image1.png" class="">
</a>

<!-- image lightbox -->
<a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img1">
<span style="background-image: url('1.png')"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php 
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
...
.....
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
?>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var hrefs = [];
var target_file = '<?php echo $target_file; ?>';
   for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
   {   
   const myArray = links[i].href.split("#");
   str = myArray[1].replace("img", "");
   hrefs.push(str);
   }
hrefs.sort();
var last = parseInt(hrefs[hrefs.length - 1]);
var next = last + 1;
var nextLink = "#img"+next;
var nextID = "img"+next;
var html = '';
html += '<li>';
html += '<a href="'+nextLink+'" class=""><img src="'+target_file+'" class=""></a>';
html += '<a href="#" class="lightbox" id="'+nextID+'"><span style="background-image: url('+target_file+')"></span></a>';
html += '</li>';
$("#parent").append(html);
</script>
<?php
} else {
echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```